# PNG image format is showing small in PDF output

Tags: pdf, xslt, png, dita-ot

I am transforming to PDF output using a ditamap file . I am trying to insert a **png** icon instead of **gif** in **Note** icon. After the transformation the result is small in png . It is working fine in svg and gif icons. I am using *DITA-OT* for the transformation.

Suggest me the solution of this .

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDq]

There is a small png icon beside Text Note.My png icon is normal ie 24x24 px.

Comment: 24x24px, but what is the resolution of your picture?

Comment: @potame same 24x24 px .. like default hand.gif  resolution stored in cfg / configuration folder. I edited the answer , image here mean by icon.

Comment: set explicit width and height values on the image. Formatters have different base resolutions and will scale images differently (FOP is 96dpi, RenderX is 120dpi for example).

Comment: @KevinBrown Thank You , problem is solved